# Getting data between two dates on a single date selection

Tags: postgresql

I want to get data between two dates in postgresql. For example if user selects a date from datepicker, let's suppose user selects '2021-06-01'. Then I want to get data of 4 days from the user selected date. I want to get data from '2021-06-01' to '2021-06-04' if user selects '2021-06-01'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date_time BETWEEN date '2021-06-01' AND (date '2021-06-01' + INTERVAL '4 DAYS')
```